# Is there a way to modify google cloud task settings?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

We have a google cloud task queue with 3000 items at 25 max concurrency and wanted to modify max concurrency though I do not see how to do this.  Is there a way to modify any of the settings on google cloud tasks queue without deleting and recreating losing all our existing items in the queue?

or a way to create a queue and just MOVE all current items from one queue to another if they have not started(or move the top 90% and leave 10% to finish in the old queue)?  Looking for any type workarounds we could do here.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through the Google Cloud SDK with `gcloud beta tasks queues update` as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/tasks/queues/update). This should modify your queue in place.

In this case, use the `--max-concurrent-dispatches` flag in order to change the maximum number of concurrent tasks.

The `--max-dispatches-per-second` flag is probably the one you want to set rate limiting.